# Windows 10 always showing wrong time (when dual-booting with Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-10, time, date-time

This is driving me crazy. For some reason Windows 10 is showing me the `UTC +00:00 London` time instead of `UTC +01:00 Vienna` although I set it accordingly:

[image]

If I **disable** "Set time automatically" and re-enable it, the time gets set correctly. However, after I reboot, the time is wrong again. Yes, I've tried to change the time-server and I've also tried to "set time zone automatically" but I'm still getting the wrong time.

How can I fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Are you able to ping, `time.windows.com`, the default NTP server?  What region do you have your installation set to?  We are currently in DST, and you have it enabled, are you 100% sure your time zone is actually changing?

Comment: [Windows 10 detecting the wrong time zone](http://superuser.com/questions/1046405/windows-10-detecting-the-wrong-time-zone?rq=1)

Comment: [Windows 10 automatic daylight savings adjustment not working?](http://superuser.com/questions/1053277/windows-10-automatic-daylight-savings-adjustment-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound Interesting - I get a time out if I ping time.windows.com - why is that? I am quite sure that I set my installation to Vienna, but even if not, I, the user, demand to see the time in UTC +1. What do you mean by "time zone is actually changing"?

Comment: So if you want to manually use a time zone, disable, "set time automatically". So answer my question about your regional settings.  In addition, tell us, what time that region is considered to be in.  What I am asking, are you sure, your time zone is changing instead of your clock being off by one hour.  I have no idea, the reason you cannot communicate with *time.microsoft.com*, try some other NTP server.

Comment: The inability to ping a server does not mean it isn't working. I can't ping time.windows.com either but it does work. many Internet servers block ping requests for security reasons.

Comment: See the answer here:  https://superuser.com/questions/1214735/how-do-i-tell-windows-to-adjust-the-time-even-if-its-waaay-off/1219885#1219885

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Dual Boot PC (Win 10 & Ubuntu 18.04). The issue was that Windows tries to keep hardware clock (a.k.a BIOS clock) at the local time, but Ubuntu tries to keep it at the UTC time. So the OSs fight each other, changing the hardware clock time each time they boot.

The solution is to either [make Ubuntu use local time](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Make_Linux_use_.27Local.27_time), or [make Windows use UTC time](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Make_Windows_use_UTC). If you use Ubuntu 15.04 or newer, then I recommend the first option, because it's as simple as executing a single command:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

Comment: THX a lot - solved the issue completely.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I made win10 use UTC time, because `timedatectl` remarks that it is adviceable to keep `rtc` in UTC-mode.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have dual boot on your computer? I've had the same issue before and how i fixed it was to change something in GRUB customizer.There's also a way to change it in windows so it might help you!

Anyway this might [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

(also windows 10, ubuntu dual boot)

Turned out the date was wrong in the BIOS settings.

Changing it there fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a dual boot Windows 10 and ubuntu machine. Even though the clock was correct in the BIOS, and the time zone was correct in Windows, the clock was always one hour behind in Windows after rebooting. The only thing that reliably fixed it for me was to change the internet time server to `pool.ntp.org`. Neither `time.windows.com` nor `time.nist.gov` worked after reboots. I'm in the UK.

Also, make sure the Windows Time service is set to start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Control Panel", click on "Clock, Language and Region", click on "Date and Time", select the "Internet Time" tab, select `time.nist.gov` from the dropdown, click "Update now".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

- Press Windows key + R
- Type services.msc.
- Double Click "Windows Time" in the Name column.
- Change "Startup type" to "Automatic" (if it’s not already set to Automatic).
- Click Start if the service isn’t started.
- Restart PC

Hope this help
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTVR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Dimension 4 app on Windows, which will automatically set the correct time:

http://www.thinkman.com/dimension4/download.htm