# Windows time updating/synchronising not working properly

Tags: windows-10, time

The Windows operating system time is always updating itself - but to a wrong time.

Usually it is 2 hours delayed backwards, but rarely it shows the right time, without doing anything.

The region is set correctly. The PC is not member of any Active Directory domain.

What I tried and experienced:

1. After manual time synchronising it gets right, until shutting down the PC.
2. Setting the time manual: this setting is reverted sometimes already before shutting down. Works in best case until next start.
3. I have tried to turn time syncing off, but after restart I had to notice that its turned on, the change lost its effect.
4. Removing all the time servers at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers` caused only that the time synchronising got permanently disabled.

Could someone help me?

Comment: You are connecting to an ntp source in a different time zone. The `w32tm` service is re-synching the time. Are you sure your region set correctly? You can also change your ntp source using command line `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org 3.pool.ntp.org"`

Comment: Also, https://superuser.com/questions/1174187/windows-10-always-showing-wrong-time

Comment: @spikey_richie, your second comment is the solution. I didn't thought Ubuntu was causing this. I cannot mark it as a solution because it's a comment, so can you post it as an answer?