# Clock always wrong [Windows 10]

Tags: windows, time

After a recent install of windows 10 I can't set the windows clock to the correct day light saving time. I've tried toggling the following settings
'set time automatically'
'set time zone automatically'
'adjust for daylight saving time automatically'

and all combinations of these settings. But after a restart the time goes back to being an hour behind.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try manually changing time zone to your own zone.  Then use automatic settings from there.

Comment: Do you dual-boot wih Linux? In that case, you might be experiencing this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1174187/windows-10-always-showing-wrong-time

Comment: Yes I was dual booting. That was the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Clocks on all modern computers work unless there is a hardware problem.

Make sure Time Zone is properly set before changing Daylight time (which indeed can be automated).

See the screen shot for changing Time Zone.

[image]