# WIndows 10 time zone keeps reverting back

Tags: windows-10, date-time, cmos, time-zone

I've got a user whose Windows 10 computer won't hold the correct time zone. Specifically, the time zone randomly changes back. The user is in Pacific Time, but the laptop would have been set up at a location in Eastern Time. The user will change the time zone in Windows 10 to PST/PDT but it will randomly change back to EST/EDT. The same happens with boot-up, sometimes the PT time zone will hold, and sometimes it will change to ET on boot-up. I wrote a batch script to change the time zone to PT on log-in, but because the random change happens while the user is on the computer as well, we need a permanent fix.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/282551/should-i-set-my-bios-to-local-time-or-utc#:%7E:text=The%20localtime%20standard%20is%20dependent,set%20by%20the%20operating%20system) question on here about CMOS clocks and how they affect the time zone setting. I was thinking to try the specific Windows registry change suggested in the one reply. However, I also wanted to post on here in case there's anything else I could check for. I've checked location services per [this other](https://superuser.com/questions/1046405/windows-10-detecting-the-wrong-time-zone) question on here, and they aren't turned on, which from what I understand, means the device IP address should influence geolocation. Additionally, the Windows time settings is set to automatically get the time from the organization's time server, which I was told doesn't influence time zone. (Though, I confess, I don't know how exactly a time server works with respect to local time zones). I even made sure to turn off "Set time zone automatically".

Any ideas?

ETA: The laptop isn't domain-joined, and the Windows profile the user logs into is a local one. The user is in the field and so the organization doesn't domain-join the field laptops.

ETA2: I'm trying to avoid, if possible, going into the BIOS settings. I work for an MSP and we do remote support, so I don't want to walk the user through BIOS settings. If nothing else seems to work, my plan is to open a ticket with the device vendor and one of their techs can walk the user through if they need to.

Comment: Is this machine connected to an AD domain server? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some advice:

- Check if the BIOS has any time-related settings
- Run *Settings > Privacy > Location* and disable
  "Allow access to location on this device" and
  "Allow apps to access your location".
- Enable the Time service and in an elevated Command Prompt run:

  ```
    net stop w32time
    w32tm /unregister
    w32tm /register
    net start w32time
  ```

  then restart the computer.
- Check if any applications are installed which are liable to change
  the time-zone. Dual-booting Windows and Linux can cause problem with the
  clock.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll be connecting with the user in about a day or so, so I'll try your suggestions and report back. I know there's no dual-booting, but I'll check for installed apps as well as the second and third ideas. Please see my ETA 2 above for your first suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Check in with your friends - the Windows Event Logs. You may find an application is adjusting the time zone. Filter the System event log for Event ID = 1 or Source = 'Kernel-General'. In our case we found the app named: "MaxproVideoGuardAgent.exe" was changing the Time zone.

Answer (score 2):

I have been suffering this issue on a Virtual Box VM. I have realized the VM was being synchronizing the time from the host. below are the steps that worked for me based from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=380292&sid=82f9d925bd2a73cfb3dddc29335c1399#p380292.

1. Shutdown the VM
2. From a command line execute the command: (The path would be different for you)
   C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage setextradata YOURVIRTUALMACHINENAME "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
3. Start the VM and change the date time as normal.

Comment: For hyper-v a similar setting exists for Integration Services->"time synchronization" which needs to be turned off. Also it helps to disable the w32time service completely so it doesn't auto start, that can be achieved by `sc config w32time start=disabled`